# Is there a better option than to drop and recreate an index at regular intervals?

Tags: cassandra

We know Indexes are not at all recommended in CASSANDRA.
However in my project its there already and Index Size is not being reduced over time and compaction.
Do we have any better option than "to drop and recreate Index on regular interval"
Kindly Suggest!!

[UPDATE FROM COMMENT] we are still in 3.11 and using Lucene.

Comment: I find the *not recommended at all* a bit strong. You need the cardinality (number of partitions where a search keyword is available) to be not too high (in the hundreds?). Indices have kept improving over time, SASI, SAI (Cassandra 5). Maybe not a solution but check `nodetool rebuild_index`

Comment: I agree,but we are still in 3.11 and using Lucene. Would definitely test nodetool rebuild_index to see if this helps any better than Index drop/recreate. We are using TWCS

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what problem you are trying to solve because it is not normal to have to do anything with indexes once they have been created.

I can't think of a reason why you would need to regularly drop-then-recreate indexes. There are very rare instances where we might suggest performing it as a one-off operation as a workaround for a bug (for example) but not as an ongoing maintenance activity.

I also noted that you mentioned you are using Lucene which indicates that you are using custom indexes so perhaps you are trying to solve a problem that isn't to do with Cassandra. In any case, if you update your original question and provide additional background information then I'd be happy to look at it again. Cheers!

Comment: Hello Erick, This Lucene Index had been created long back to have some specific query result on non key columns.We are using TWCS which is dropping the SSTABLES per TTL and GC_GRACE_SECONDS,however Lucene index cleanup is not happening automatically.We could see the older files in Lucene folder. Team is doing drop and recreate this Lucene Index to resolve this.